Understanding the Product as a Universal Arrow from the Diagonal Functor
This is my first question and it has been asked before, but I'm not comfortable with the answer so I thought I'd raise it again. 
In Mac Lane's Categories for the Working Mathematician it is claimed that given a category $\ \mathcal{C}$ and a product of elements $(a,b)$ with $a,\ b \in \mathcal{C}$, the diagonal functor $\Delta : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ has a universal arrow to any product of elements $(a,b)$, where such an arrow is a pair $\langle r, v \rangle$ with $r \in \text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $v: \Delta(r) = (r,r) \to (a,b)$ satisfying the property that for another pair $\langle s,w\rangle$ of the same form, there is a unique arrow $f: r\to s$ such that $v\circ(f,f) = s$. The claim is that the universal arrow is the pair $(p,q)$ where $p$ is the projection map to $a$ and $q$ is the projection map to $b$.
The problem I have with this is that we want an object $d$ associated to the arrow $(p,q)$ with $\Delta(d) = (a,b)$, and such an object should not exist. It seems to me that this problem with the definitions involved is irreconcilable, so I'd really like to hear (a) if there's a way to fix this or (b) supposing the approach cannot be used to interpret the product as a universal arrow, a different functor I could try to obtain the result.

What other answer have you seen?

This was discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519274/product-projections-are-a-universal-arrow?rq=1. I actually think I see how the answer works now!

Use \langle and \rangle for delimiters, not < and >, which are operators.

thank you! Is it appropriate to answer my own question and clarify my point of confusion or should I just delete?

@Corlio I personally would encourage self-answering in this situation.

This actually isn't too hard to resolve. Recall that when the product $a\times b$ exists, it is an object of $\mathcal{C}$ with $\Delta(a\times b) = (a\times b, a\times b)$. Now the pair $\langle a\times b, (p , q)\rangle$ satisfies the definition of universal arrow, precisely using the usual universal property of the product.
